# ¿Cómo ordenar los contornos?

Tags: python, opencv

tengo este problema con mi código, en algunas imágenes los números son ordenados correctamente y en otras ocasiones se ordenan de una manera aleatoria, no he encontrado una solución, agradecería su ayuda.
Gracias de antemano.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.perspective import four_point_transform
from imutils import contours
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", required=True,
help="path to the input image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# load the image and resize it to a smaller factor so that
# the shapes can be approximated better
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

# define the dictionary of digit segments so we can identify
# each digit on the thermostat
DIGITS_LOOKUP = {
(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1): 0,
(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 1,
(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1): 2,   #2
(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0): 2,
(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 7,   #7
(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 3,
(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0): 4,
(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1): 5,
(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1): 6,
(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0): 7,
(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1): 8,
(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1): 9
}

# pre-process the image by resizing it, converting it to
# graycale, blurring it, and computing an edge map
image = imutils.resize(image, height=500)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 50, 200, 255)

# find contours in the edge map, then sort them by their
# size in descending order
cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)
displayCnt = None
cv2.drawContours(image, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
# approximate the contour
peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * peri, True)

# if the contour has four vertices, then we have found
# the thermostat display
if len(approx) == 4:
    displayCnt = approx
    break

# extract the thermostat display, apply a perspective transform
# to it
warped = four_point_transform(gray, displayCnt.reshape(4, 2))
output = four_point_transform(image, displayCnt.reshape(4, 2))

warped = imutils.resize(warped, height=400)
output = imutils.resize(output, height=400)

# threshold the warped image, then apply a series of morphological
# operations to cleanup the thresholded image
thresh = cv2.threshold(warped, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (1, 5))
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)

# find contours in the thresholded image, then initialize the
# digit contours lists
cnts = cv2.findContours(dilation.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
digitCnts = []
cv2.drawContours(output,cnts,-1,(0,255,0),2)

# loop over the digit area candidates
for c in cnts:
# compute the bounding box of the contour
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)

if x >=100 and x<=260 and (y >= 80 and y<= 300):
# if the contour is sufficiently large, it must be a digit
    if w >= 10 and w<= 70 and (h >= 60 and h <= 80):
        digitCnts.append(c)


cv2.drawContours(output,digitCnts,-1,(0,0,255),2)
# sort the contours from left-to-right, then initialize the
# actual digits themselves
digitCnts = contours.sort_contours(digitCnts,
method="left-to-right")[0]
digitCnts = contours.sort_contours(digitCnts, method="top-to-bottom")[0]
digits = []

# loop over each of the digits
for c in digitCnts:
# extract the digit ROI
(x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
roi = thresh[y:y + h, x:x + w]

if w>=10 and w<=30 and (h>=60 and h<=80):
    digit = 1
    digits.append(digit)
    cv2.rectangle(output, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
    cv2.putText(output, str(digit), (x - 10, y - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)
else:

    # compute the width and height of each of the 7 segments
    # we are going to examine
    (roiH, roiW) = roi.shape
    (dW, dH) = (int(roiW * 0.15), int(roiH * 0.15))
    dHC = int(roiH * 0.05)

    # define the set of 7 segments
    segments = [
        ((0, 0), (w, dH)),  # top
        ((0, 0), (dW, h // 2)), # top-left
        ((w - dW, 0), (w, h // 2)), # top-right
        ((0, (h // 2) - dHC) , (w, (h // 2) + dHC)), # center
        ((0, h // 2), (dW, h)), # bottom-left
        ((w - dW, h // 2), (w, h)), # bottom-right
        ((0, h - dH), (w, h))   # bottom
    ]
    on = [0] * len(segments)

    # loop over the segments
    for (i, ((xA, yA), (xB, yB))) in enumerate(segments):
        # extract the segment ROI, count the total number of
        # thresholded pixels in the segment, and then compute
        # the area of the segment
        segROI = roi[yA:yB, xA:xB]
        total = cv2.countNonZero(segROI)
        area = (xB - xA) * (yB - yA)

        # if the total number of non-zero pixels is greater than
        # 50% of the area, mark the segment as "on"
        if total / float(area) > 0.5:
            on[i]= 1
    # lookup the digit and draw it on the image
    digit = DIGITS_LOOKUP[tuple(on)]
    digits.append(digit)
    cv2.rectangle(output, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
    cv2.putText(output, str(digit), (x - 10, y - 10),
        cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.65, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# display the digits
if len(digits) == 4:
    print(u"{}{}/{}{} mmHg".format(*digits))

if len(digits) == 5:
        print(u"{}{}{}/{}{} mmHg".format(*digits))

if len(digits) == 6:
        print(u"{}{}{}/{}{}{} mmHg".format(*digits))

cv2.imshow("D", dilation)
cv2.imshow("T", thresh)
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.imshow("Warped", warped)
cv2.imshow("Output", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Adjunto 2 imágenes para ejemplo
[image: example0.jpg]

[image: f20.jpg]